# Django coverage logout test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, coverage.py, test-coverage

Im using coverage to test this view from views.py :

```
class Login(View):
    template_name = ['cost_control_app/login.html', 'cost_control_app/home.html']

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UsersForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name[0],{"form":form,})


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            if user.is_active:
                form_group = GroupsForm()
                lista = definetree(request.user.groups.all()[0].name, request.user.id)
                return render_to_response(self.template_name[1], {"form_group" : form_group,
                                                               "groups":lista[0],
                                                               "subgroups":lista[1] ,
                                                               "sub_subgroups":lista[2],
                                                               "cost_items":lista[3],
                                                               "count_requests":lista[4],
                                                                },RequestContext(request))
            else:
                logout_view(request)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cost_control_app:login'))


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request) 
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cost_control_app:login'))
```

This is my test fot that view in test_views.py :

```
class test_login_out(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['test_data_cost_control_app.json']

    def test_login_get(self):
        request = HttpRequest()
        request.method = 'GET'
        Login.as_view()(request)

    def test_login_post(self):
        request = HttpRequest()
        request.method = 'POST'
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        tuser = User.objects.create_user(
        username='jsanchesan', email='jacob@test.com', password='abcd1234')
        search = User.objects.get(username = tuser.username)
        search.is_active = False
        search.save()
        request.POST['username'] = search.username
        request.POST['password'] = 'abcd1234'
        engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
        session_key = None
        request.session = engine.SessionStore(session_key)
        Login.as_view()(request)
```

It goes well until it calls the logout_view(request) function because throws me this error:

> -> logout_view(request) (Pdb) n KeyError: 'SERVER_NAME'

Any idea why ?, thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing the return: `return logout_view(request)`

Comment: when are you calling logout_view() in your test? Can you post the full backtrace for the exception.

Comment: Where do i need to call that return Timmy ? , and Haken, im calling it in the else of user.is_active inside the view

Comment: Add the backtrace to your question.

Comment: Of course, i already updated my question and here it is too :  -> logout_view(request)
(Pdb) n
KeyError: 'SERVER_NAME'